# how can I pull react-select's drop-down menu above(it's z-index) ExpansionPanel?

Tags: material-ui, z-index, react-select

I've used react-select in ExpansionPanel(a component of material-ui) , it has made ExpansionPanel an unwanted scroll. how can I fix it? I tried to change z-index , but didn't work. consider third select in picture, it's drop down been hidden by  ExpansionPanel. thank you in advance.

[image]

```
                <Select
                   value={state.selectedPerson}
                   onChange={handleMitarbeiterChange}
                   options={state.peopleOptions}
                   textFieldProps={{
                   label: 'Mitarbeiter',
                   id: "mitarbeiter-required",
                   InputLabelProps: {
                     shrink: true,
                   },
                 }}
                />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I searched in many resources and tried many ways (such as z-index, overflow, position, ...), non of them worked . finally I found the answer on this link :
[enter link description here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3263)

and this is the answer that worked for me:

If you are using v2 of react-select, you can use the menuPortalTarget prop to render the dropdown into a parent container (e.g. body) of the footer.

```
<Select
    { ... }
    menuPortalTarget={document.querySelector('body')}
/>
```

Comment: Best answer ever. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Add these bold line in your all Select tag

```
<Select ......

1. menuPortalTarget={document.body} 2. styles={{ menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}

...... />
```

Comment: This even works while you're in a dropdown menu that contains React-select. Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

After seeing the half dozen related issues, yet not finding a resolution, I have found one.

```
<Select
    menuPortalTarget={document.body}
    menuPosition={'fixed'} 
/>
```

Add these two options to your Select component.

It appears to make us of the new React Portal feature.

EDIT: If you do the above, you then run into this problem with the menu anchoring to the page. https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4088